# Git: name and email address configuration

Tags: git

Once in a while I get the message shown below from Git. My questions regarding this are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I prevent this from happening again?
3. How does this affect my commits or any other Git actions I may take?

I realize similar questions have been posted to Stack Overflow, but I don't believe they address this message ***in particular***.

---

Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email you@example.com
```

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

Comment: Are you getting this on the same workstation when working under the same user account, and you can guarantee the user's configuration directory is always available? The idea is that global git configuration is stored in the `.gitconfig` file located in your per-user configuration directory. Since you told us exactly zero info about your system, I can't guess much more.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`Git` simply detects you don't have the following section in your config files:

```
[user]
    name = <your name>
    email = <your mail>
```

- `<project_path>/.git/config` for the project specific config file.
- `~/.gitconfig` the global config file

When you do:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email you@example.com
```

Git writes that information into the configuration file (`--global` means in the global config file).

To have a the correct Author section in a commit like the following example commit:

```
commit 79eeaa9f22321580a0e5bee6e237331691cd3b68
Author: Sandro Munda <foo@bar.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 8 10:40:05 2012 +0200

    My first commit
```

You need to reset the commit information with the command:

`git commit --amend --reset-author`

Comment: If git "detects" a lack of config files, why doesn't it give a better error message?

Comment: @pabrams The error message clearly points out that you should use the `git config` commands shown above to set your name and address. You don't need to know about config files for that.

Answer (score 12):

That's simply because you didn't set your global user.name and user.email and so git has to guess them when creating a new repository.

Use this :

```
git config --global user.email "some@email.com"
git config --global user.name "ha"
```

So next time those settings will be used.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent git from guessing automatic values you can set

```
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-useruseConfigOnly

Comment: Came here looking for this option, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the default user name and email for you "desktop user account".

Follow the instructions that you posted to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As my ChatGPT advised me,

You can use a specific email for **each** git repository. If you use more git accounts, this might come in handy.

```
git config user.email "some@email.com"
```

Note that it excludes the `--global` flag.